# Custom block created in module not visible on frontend

Tags: magento

I have created the below layout reference in config.xml

```
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <quickcontact module="Brijesh_Quickcontact">
                <file>quickcontact.xml</file>
            </quickcontact>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

frontend/default/default/layout/quickcontact.xml  has the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="right">
              <block type="core/template" name="quickcontact"  
                template="quickcontact/form.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

frontend/default/default/template/quickcontact/form.phtml has some text in it.

When i visit the home page, the content of form.phtml is not displayed on the right.  I am using magento 1.9.0.1 version of magento.

Comment: You home page is on 3 columns or 2 column-right?

Answer (score 0):

I moved layout and template file to base and it worked fine.  Hope this helps someone facing similar problem